# Angular keyvalue -> How to iterate again when key is array?

Tags: angular, loops, object, key-value

How to iterate again through my object key when it is an array?

Here my HTML:

```
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let duplicate of duplicates | keyvalue; let i = index ">
    <th scope="row"> {{duplicate.key}} </th>
    <th scope="row"> {{duplicate.value}} </th>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Here are my example objects. I have multiple ID's because it is showing me duplicates with same data but different ID's I need to display them in form of table one near another that's why I need to iterate through ID's key array

```
{
        "_id": [
            "62582bee93a35f434618668d",
            "62582baf93a35f434618663f",
            "62582be393a35f4346186681"
        ],
        "title": "Jr",
        "salutation": "Dr",
        "firstName": "Gerianna",
        "lastName": "Favela",
        "companyName": "Brainbox",
        "business": false,
        "street": "51 Elgar Terrace",
        "city": "Eger",
        "postcode": "3304",
        "email": "gfavela1i@flavors.me",
        "phone": "957-614-0302"
},
{
        "_id": [
            "62582baf93a35f434618663d",
            "62582be393a35f434618667f"
        ],
        "title": "IV",
        "salutation": "Mrs",
        "firstName": "Marrilee",
        "lastName": "Glede",
        "companyName": "Rhyloo",
        "business": true,
        "street": "52668 Knutson Drive",
        "city": "Río Ceballos",
        "postcode": "5113",
        "email": "mglede1g@jiathis.com",
        "phone": "658-769-1436"
},
```

Comment: Just create a inner loop `let id of duplicate.value._ids` (see that "duplicate" is the variable you use in the outer loop)

Answer (score 0):

Try nested *ngIf if you want to iterate through ID's key array.

```
*ngFor="let duplicate of duplicates"
   *ngFor="let companyId of duplicate"
```

One thing to remember is performance issues if you have large data set. In that case, you should move the process to your ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've used outer loop this is how I made it, and I have displayed every duplicate separately for each ID.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let duplex of duplicates._id | keyvalue; let i = index ">
    <h4>{{duplex.value}}</h4>
  <tr *ngFor="let duplicate of duplicates | keyvalue; let i = index ">
    <ng-container *ngIf="duplicate.key !== '_id'">
    <th scope="row"> {{duplicate.key}}</th>
    <th scope="row"> {{duplicate.value}} </th>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```